# Which datetime picker just works with active admin 0.5.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am seeking for **tested** date & time picker that **just works** with active admin 0.5.0.

I am digging for hours now, I've read dozens of existing discussions on stackoverflow and many other resources found in the net.

I've encountered problems with virtually any datetime picker script. For instance, activeadmin's wiki page [Combine datetime picker with active_admin](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/wiki/Combine-datetime-picker-with-active_admin) no longer apply to 0.5.0. Result looks [like this](http://tinypic.com/r/2wqe4j9/6).

Some of them suffer from CSS inheritance - active admin applies a lot of styling, and if picker's author had not avoided that, it requires manually styling indefinite amount of CSS properties just to revert changes.

I cannot rely on such scripts. It is not because I am lazy, or I am unable to fix them. There's just too big risk of breaking such hacks in case of updating any of dependent gems/libraries related to active admin.

Anyone can recommend working solution that won't suffer from such problems?

Comment: I assume you've tried JQuery datepicker. Was the problem with that the CSS styling?   If so, have you tried simply not including the jquery styling files in your project?

Comment: i really don't understand why the included a datepicker, but no datetime-picker. it's just ridiculous!

Comment: @LisaD: it is due to activeadmin's styling, obviously I cannot disable activeadmin's CSS and continue using activeadmin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just created a gem for that:

https://github.com/saepia/just-datetime-picker

Comment: can this be used only as a timepicker, without showing the date picker?

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the DateNTimePickerActiveAdmin Rubygem. It works really well and is customisable according to your project.

You can find the documentation here: https://github.com/NikhithaGraceJosh/date_n_time_picker_activeadmin

From the docs:

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'date_n_time_picker_activeadmin'
```

**Code Sample (In your form)**

```
f.input :column_name, as: :datetimepicker
```

**CSS**

In active_admin.scss, add the line,

```
@import date_n_time_picker_activeadmin
```

**JS**

In active_admin.js, add the line,

```
//= require date_n_time_picker_activeadmin
```

Hope it's useful!

Answer (score 0):

**just-datetime-picker gem** doesn't seem to be maintained since last year, so better to use **pickadate-rails gem**.

Checkout this  [Integrating datepicker and timepicker with active admin](http://kiprosh.com/blog/integrating-datepicker-and-timepicker-with-active-admin)